# Data without using .ToList is also send to api, but how?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, webapi2

In web api the data without using `.ToList()` is also send to api, but how?
This is my LINQ query and I do not use the `.ToList()` but my data is also sent to the browser.can anyone please tell me the difference or can describe that how it is working?

```
using (var _context = new iCMEFModelCon())
                {
                    return _context.UserResidents.Where(c => c.ResidentId == residentId)
                        .Select(c => new
                        {
                            UserId = c.User.Id,
                            UserName = ((c.User.FirstName ?? "") + " " + (c.User.LastName ?? "")).Trim()
                        });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the query is either IEnumerable or IQueryable:

The result of a Linq database query is typically `IQueryable< T>` which is derived from `IEnumerable< T>, IQueryable,` and `IEnumerable`.

If your data source is an `IEnumerable`, the result type is`IEnumerable< T>`

[Find More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371834/rules-of-thumb-for-when-to-call-tolist-when-returning-linq-results)